# How to write text in small font

Tags: support, markdown, editor, fonts

I remember seeing some questions and answers in which some text was written in small fonts, but, I haven't found a matching tag in the [whitelisted HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites). How did they do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect either the `<sup>` or `<sub>` tags, or a combination of both.

<sup>You know, like this?</sup>

<sub>Or this?</sub>

<sup><sub>Or even, this.</sub></sup>

```
<sup>You know, like this?</sup>

<sub>Or this?</sub>

<sup><sub>Or even, this.</sub></sup>
```

Comment: I find that `<sub><sup>` is better vertically aligned than `<sup><sub>`

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This was just a miracle</sub> <sub><sub>and you didn't actually see any small fonts, <sup>forget and relax :)</sup></sub></sub>

In other words, place your text in `<sub></sub>` or `<sup></sup>` tags. The first one is subscript, the second is superscript - but they are abused to make small text :D

You can also use multiple `<sub>`s or `<sup>`s, or combine them, that's what I've done in my example and the markdown is:

```
<sub>This was just a miracle</sub> <sub><sub>and you didn't actually see any small fonts, <sup><sup>forget and relax :)</sup> </sub></sub></sub>
```

And to let you  understand the hierarchy :

```
<sub>
    This was just a miracle
</sub>
<sub>
    <sub>
        and you didn't actually see any small fonts,
        <sup>
            <sup>
                forget and relax :)
            </sup>
        </sup>
    </sub>
</sub>
```